# If not exists query results in "error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: sql, vb.net

I would like to insert a row with SQL (in Visual Basic) and receive something like: "Error: You have an errin in your SQL syntax near IF NOT EXISTS ... at line 1"

Code looks like:

```
...
Try

    query = "IF NOT EXISTS (Select Movie_Name from MovieDB where Movie_Name=" & placeholder & ") INSERT INTO MovieDB (Movie_Name) VALUES ('" & placeholder & "')"

    'PREPARE CONNECTION
    MySQLCmd = New MySqlCommand(query, dbConnection)

    'OPEN DB 
    dbConnection.Open()

    'EXECUTE QUERY
    MySQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    'CLOSE DB
    dbConnection.Close()

Catch ex As Exception
    ...
```

I really dont get it anymore. Some ideas?

Comment: Where are you getting `placeholder` from, and what does it contain?

Comment: Is this Visual Basic.NET or VBA?

Comment: @DStanley [tag:vba] doesn't have Catch, so this is VB.Net

Comment: placeholder is a value from checkbox. When I check from a checkbox-list some movies, in placeholder will be the name of the checkbox (moviename) like "ABC.mkv".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know "IF NOT EXISTS INSERT" is no valid MySQL syntax. This should work:

```
query = "INSERT INTO MovieDB (Movie_Name) VALUES ('" & placeholder & "') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Movie_Name = Movie_Name";
```

This tries to insert the new movie name and if this fails it does virtually nothing. (For this to work there must be a unique index on Movie_Name.)

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum you need single quotes around the first string as well:

```
                                                                      --V                 --V
query = "IF NOT EXISTS (Select Movie_Name from MovieDB where Movie_Name='" & placeholder & "'); INSERT INTO MovieDB (Movie_Name) VALUES ('" & placeholder & "')"
```

As @Cameron astutely noticed, you also need a semicolon between the `EXISTS` function and the `INSERT` command

But you should look into using parameters instead of concatenating SQL - not only does it remove the need to delimit strings, but it prevents SQL injection and avoids syntax error if the string contains an apostrophe.

Comment: with the code above i receive this: Error: writeToDB You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS (Select Movie_Name from MovieDB where Movie_Name='Enemy 2.mkv'' at line 1.        I think there is now a ' to much...?